# Embeded youtube videos slow web down

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I add a bunch of embedded youtube videos (10-20 videos) to my website and I think that they slow my website down

My question is how to fix it or what is the right way to do it?

Currently, I just add them to my website with iframe like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZD0AYXseGXk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Adding 10-20 iframes is basically loading 10-20 new pages so that is quite a lot to load, especially on slower devices. You might want to look into loading them when they are scrolled into view or something instead.

Comment: Do you know how can I lazy load them?

Comment: Sure, but that is also well documented everywhere on the internet. Look into the Intersection Observer API and you'll find what you need.

Comment: This might be interesting: https://css-tricks.com/lazy-load-embedded-youtube-videos/

Answer (score 2):

I think that we have to use the video lazy load. So when the page is loading, we have to use the HTML image tag. If the user clicks on the image, we can load the YouTube video using an `iframe` and then play it.

You can get the thumbnail URL from the YouTube video.

```
<div class="video" data-video="youtube video url">
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
</div>

<script>
$("document").ready(function(e) {
    $(".video").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
        var video_id = $(this).attr('data-video');
        $(".video").html('<iframe src="' + video_id + "'>");
    });
});
</script>
```